# How to solve limits when x approaches minus value?

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus, limits, epsilon-delta

How to solve the following limit?

I can't think of a way to find $\delta$ values because x approaches a minus value . 
$$\lim_{x\to -3} x^2+5x+6=0$$

Comment: It seems you want to prove the limit has value $0$. Try factoring $x^2+5x+6$ first, and work with that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We want to show that for every $\epsilon$ there is a $\delta$ so that if $0<|x+3|<\delta$, then $|x^2+5x+6|<\epsilon$. Suppose $|x+3|<\delta$, then $|x^2+5x+6| = |x+3||x+2|<\delta |x+2|$. If we additionally assume $\delta < 1$, then we have:
$$|x+3|<1$$
$$-1 < x+3 < 1$$
$$-2 < x+2 < 0$$
$$|x+2|<2$$

So $|x^2+5x+6|<2\delta$. This means that if we choose $\delta = \min(1,\frac{\epsilon}{2})$, we have:

$$|x^2+5x+6| = |x+3||x+2|<\delta \cdot 2 \leq \epsilon$$

Answer (score 2):

**HINT :**
$$
x^2+5x+6=(x+2)(x+3).
$$

Answer (score 1):

I think you should rewrite the expression as $(x+3)(x+2) = (x-(-3))(x-(-3)-1)$ and then use the fact that $|x-(-3)|< \delta$